# Regex for a letter as first char and four digits after

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to have a regex to validate a string starting with a letter and then digits, but the string length should be limited to 5 chars.

Regex Expression I am using:

```
Validators.pattern('(.*?)[0-9]{4}')
```

Unfortunately, it does not give me validation message (error message) when the digit is more than 5. Could you please check my regex expression and tell me where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `.*?` matches *any* *0 or more*  chars. Maybe you need just `Validators.pattern('.[0-9]{4}')`

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew said, the `.` will match any character (including digits) and you are matching 0 or more of those. If you only want 1 non-numeric character before the numbers, then you do not want to use a modifier and should use a character class that excludes digits.

Example: `Validators.pattern('[^0-9][0-9]{4}')`

Comment: So, the whole input should be 5 chars long, and the first one can be any char (letters/digits/special characters)?

Comment: Wiktor. First character should be input.It does not give you the true answer. First character needs to be char and others should be number.

Comment: What is a "char" in your language?

Comment: char is the shortage of character . It means "letter"

Comment: A `&` is also a "character". "B" is a letter. Now, do you expect letters like `я` in your input?

Comment: 23232 is also working in the validation that you provided Wiktor and c3st7n

Comment: Sorry victor I meant letter then. Not character

Comment: Validators.pattern('[^0-9][0-9]{4}'),  is the correct answer that I need. Thank you guys

Comment: `Validators.pattern('[^0-9][0-9]{4}')` will probably match too much based on your more recent comments. You should try `Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z][0-9]{4}')`

Comment: `[^0-9]` (*any character but digits*) does not match only letters. It will match `$`, and `&` etc. `[A-Za-z]` won't match `ę`.

Comment: Exactly. [^0-9] gives me all chars such like '#.' A small correction  Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z][0-9]{4}') is the correct answer

Comment: why - voting ? who gives - voting ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.*?` pattern matches any 0+ characters (by a character, I mean all possible symbols, letters, digits), as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns.

What you need is to match a single ASCII letter at the start of the string, and then assure there are just 4 digits after it. Since `Validators.pattern()` patterns are anchored by default, you just need to use

```
Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z][0-9]{4}')
```

The pattern will get translated to `/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{4}$/`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3tl0sK/1).

NOTE: if you ever need to match this pattern inside a longer string to extract the pattern occurrences, use word boundaries instead of anchors, `\b[A-Za-z][0-9]{4}\b`.